# Auto silent install by powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make autoinstall my application by powershell.

I am trying like this

```
$command = "cmd.exe /c C:\myApp_Installer.exe /s /v /qn"
$process = [WMICLASS]"\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"
$process.Create($command)
```

Installer starts but I still must click Install button.

Comment: I don't think it's related to Powershell but to your app that maybe does not accept silent install. Are you sure of the parameters?

Comment: @ManuP ohh ok I understand. Thank you. I'll fix it

Comment: There is no "magic parameter" that will make any application install silently. You need to check which options your particular installer provides and proceed from there.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I see that there is a problem with Windows because it's not trusted application because it comes from internet.

Comment: Internet Explorer has a useless feature that adds an [alternate data stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/) "Zone.Identifier" with this information to downloaded files. Remove the stream from the file, either with PowerShell as described in the Technet blog post or by clicking "Unblock" in the file's properties.

Comment: @Defus in the directory where your installer is: `.\myApp_Installer.exe /?` or `.\myApp_Installer.exe --help` to check which options your installer provides.

Comment: @Jelphy there is output http://imgur.com/a/Z4Q1g

Comment: As you can see it's only the first layer of your installer that this output is shown for. It's likely unpacking a secondary installer. As you're saying it's your installer, how did you build it? Just as side note with current PS versions there is also a `Unblock-File` cmdlet.